# need help fixing my sql code

Tags: sql, union

so i have this question:
Write an SQL Statement that displays details of movies (name, genre and classification). Display only movies that are not 'crime' based and the name is not a single word (E.g. 'lion' is a single word movie name whereas 'suicide squad' is not a single word).

and i think i have to use a union statement, but what i have been doing is not working.

```
SELECT MOVIEGENRE, MOVIENAME
FROM MOVIE 
WHERE MOVIEGENRE NOT LIKE '%CRIME%'

UNION

SELECT MOVIENAME, MOVIEGENRE 
FROM MOVIE
WHERE MOVIENAME NOT LIKE '% %';
```

can anyone help me out?

i keep getting this output:

```
MOVIEGENRE           MOVIENAME          
-------------------- --------------------
ADVENTURE            PETES DRAGON        
ANIMATION            FINDING DORY        
CRIMINAL             CRIME               
HORROR               LIGHTS OUT          
HORROR               THE CONJURING 2     
NERVE                CRIME
```

btw im a 1st year uni student :)

Comment: What database are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your two conditions for filtering into a single `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT MOVIEGENRE,
       MOVIENAME
FROM MOVIE
WHERE MOVIEGENRE NOT LIKE '%CRIME%' AND  -- not crime based
      MOVIENAME LIKE '% %'               -- name is two or more words
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MOVIEGENRE, MOVIENAME
FROM MOVIE 
WHERE MOVIEGENRE NOT LIKE '%CRIME%'
AND INSTR(MOVIENAME,' ',1,1)=0
```

You do not require union all just And condition is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server`,Use the below script.

```
SELECT MOVIEGENRE, MOVIENAME
FROM MOVIE 
WHERE MOVIEGENRE NOT LIKE '%CRIME%' --Getting MOVIEGENRE which is not crime
 AND LTRIM(RTRIM(MOVIENAME)) like '% %' --Getting MOVIENAME contains more than one word
```